# Make on-screen button signal act like Keyboard signals

Tags: elm, elm-signal

The core `Keyboard` signals, `Keyboard.space` for example, are `True` when the given key is pressed and `False` otherwise. I want to give the signal from an on-screen button the same property.

I've got a button that sends a `Bool` to a mailbox, but it always remains `True` unless I send another message, but I can't find a clean way to do that after I use the value from the signal, and it would be nice to not have to worry if I decide to have multiple functions reading from the same mailbox later.

I think there might be a way to this with `Signal.foldp` but if so, I can't find a good example of something similar. What would most conveinient is if there was a function with the signature `Signal Bool -> Signal Bool` that would transform the signal into one that sent a `False` after each `True` is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
Signal.dropRepeats <| Time.since Time.millisecond <| yourMailbox.signal
```

but it is advisable to use Elm Architecture and just think in terms of Actions rather than drop to such low level.

Comment: Well what I'm doing is recreating an abstraction that already exists for the keyboard buttons. I've got this saved as a module so I don't need to do this "low level" stuff ever again.